# Eloquent/Laravel5 linking distant relations ("hasOneThrough")

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, pivot-table, has-one-through

**The question in short:**

"pages" and "tasks" have a many-to-many relationship linked by the pivot table  "page_tasks". The table "responses" is linked to that pivot table by the foreign key "page_task_id".

Now I want to be able to access the page and the task a response belongs to directly with Eloquent. However the hasManyThrough function does not work, as it exspects the foreign_keys at different places:

```
 public function task(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough('PageTask', 'Task', 'page_task_id', 'task_id');
}
```

> > Unknown column 'tasks.page_task_id' in 'field list'

This means that eloquent exspects the task table having a foreign key page_task_id pointing to page_tasks. But in my model the page_tasks table has a foreign key task_id pointing to tasks. How do I tell eloquent that fact?

An other approach I tried was to use existing relations that were previously defined:

```
public function task(){
    return $this->page_task->task();
}
```

This however tells me that there is no methoid called "task".

What would the recommended way be to achieve this? What am I doing wrong?

---

**Here are some more details if needed:**

"pages" and "tasks" have a many-to-many relationship with pivot table page_tasks linking it.

Page-Model:

```
class Page extends Model {
    public function tasks(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Task', 'page_tasks');
    }
}
```

Task-Model:

```
class Task extends Model {
    public function pages()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Page', 'page_tasks');
    }
}
```

This works fine.

Response-Model looks like this

```
class Response extends Model {
    protected $fillable = [
        'page_task_id',
    ];

    public function page_task(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\PageTask', 'page_tasks');
    }

    public function task(){
         ??????
    }
}
```

PageTask-Model looks like this:

```
class PageTask extends Model {
    protected $fillable = [
        'page_id',
        'task_id',
     ];
    public function page(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Page');
    }
    public function task(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Task');
    }
    public function responses(){
        return $this->hasMany('Response');
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than showing us your models (which _is_ helpful), what are you trying to do? What do you want to call from where?

Comment: First of all, you should define a separate model for Responses and define the relationships Response-Task, as well as Response-Page separately within that model. You shouldn't be using the pivot table to link any other model to the related ones as it ISN'T the Laravel way.

Comment: I defined a separate model and the relationship Response-Task is exactly what I'm trying to model but does not work.

Comment: So you say, that it is not the eloquent active record way to do this. I was thinking of that and in my opinion when one key holds all the information, why storing 2 redundant keys? Are there other opinions on that subject?

Comment: look at this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994640/laravel-hasmanythrough