# Laravel eloquent insert data with multiple relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 3 tables:

```
User
    - id
    - email

UserAccount
    - id
    - user_id
    - account_id

Account
    - id
    - user_id

Verification
    - id
    - user_id
    - guid
```

I am trying to achieve a post whenever I try to add a `user`, it will automatically add an `account` with empty fields but with `user_id` in it, `Verification` table with `user_id` also, at the same time once the `Account` has been created it should also record `UserAccount` `user_id` and `account_id` but I ended up this error using many to many relationship `belongsToMany` and `sync`. How do I add the `acct_id` and `user_id` with eloquent?

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'acct_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `user_accounts` (`acct_id`, `user_id`) values (?, 17))
```

This is what I've tried so far.

Controller.php

```
$user = new User();
$user->name = "Not set";
$user->email = $email;
$user->password = NULL;
$user->save();

$accounts = new Account();
$accounts->email = $email;
$user->account()->save($accounts);

$userAccount = new UserAccount();
$userAccount->userAccount()->sync([
   $user->id,
   $accounts->id
]);
```

User.php

```
public function account()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Account::class);
}

public function userAccount()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, UserAccount::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

UserACcount.php

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}

public function account()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Account::class, 'acct_id', 'id');
}

public function userAccount()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Account::class, UserAccount::class, 'acct_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Verification.php

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Account.php

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}

public function userAccount()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(UserAccount::class);
}
```

I tried using this functionality and completely works fine but pretty sure this is how it works with eloquent.

```
$userAcct = new UserAccount();
$userAcct->create([
    'user_id' => $user->id,
    'acct_id' => $accounts->id
]);
```

Any thoughts?

I also have did found this related problem ([Laravel hasManyThrough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994640/laravel-hasmanythrough))

Comment: Is it possible for you to update the database structure? Because it seems like your `User <=> Account` relation should be a `Many to Many` with `UserAccount` as pivot. (my answer will depend on yours)

Comment: @Shizzen83 yes, what should I need to do?

Comment: Gonna write everything as an answer, wait for 5 minutes

Comment: @Shizzen83 no worries I can wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should remove `user_id` from the `account` table because it is already referenced by `user_account` which links both tables. Moreover, if you wanna take advantages of Eloquent conventions which allow it to guess table names and fields, you should make sure your tables are named `users`, `accounts`, `verifications` and `account_user`.

User.php

```
public function accounts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Account::class);
}
```

Account.php

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

The `UserAccount` model is useless if `account_user` exists only to links 2 tables.

Then, you may use an observer to get an event-based approach: whenever an user is created => do something

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\Account;
use App\Verification;

class UserObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the User "created" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function created(User $user)
    {
        (new Verification)->user()->associate($user);
        $account = new Account;
        $account->save();
        $user->accounts()->attach([
            $account->id
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: After rereading it, I may fail my understanding of your tables, may you confirm the relation between users and accounts pls? 1 user <=> n accounts or n users <=> n accounts?

Comment: users can have many accounts, as well as the accounts, has many users. tried working your solution but `Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db.account_user' doesn't exist` I'm still looking on the model if there is anything that I missed

Comment: Yes, I told you Eloquent would try to guess the pivot name : concatenate by `_` of 2 tables in alphabetical order => `account_user`. You have 2 choices: rename the SQL table or add your pivot name here `$this->belongsToMany(Account::class, here);` and `return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, here);`

Comment: I changed the SQL table and this is the output `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'account_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `account_user` (`account_id`, `user_id`) values (?, 46))`, for the pivot name what should i put on the "here" in `belongsToMany`?

Comment: you don't need to change anything other if you updated the pivot table name ;) list the fields of this table please

Comment: for the table `account_user` just the `account_id` and `user_id`), `verification` has `id`, `user_id`, `guid`, `account` has `id, `email`, and so on with so much fields, `user` the default fields

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196446/discussion-between-shizzen83-and-boang3000).

Answer (score 0):

```
// Post Model
 public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category')->withTimestamps();
    }
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag')->withTimestamps();
    }

//User Model
 public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }

//Category Model

 public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post')->withTimestamps();
    }

//Tag Model 

public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post')->withTimestamps();
    }
```