# How insert a query into a database using Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have this query

```
$data = DB::table('incidencias')
   ->join('clientes_incid', 'clientes_incid.rif', '=', 'incidencias.rif')
   ->select('incidencias.rif')
   ->distinct()
   ->get();
```

And I want to insert the information of this query in a new table in my database

How could I do that? somebody can help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel eloquent insert data with multiple relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57031129/laravel-eloquent-insert-data-with-multiple-relationship)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new instance of a model, append the data, and then save it. You can use relationships to join the data to the other table.

Example:

```
$user = new User();
$user->name = "Not set";
$user->email = $email;
$user->password = NULL;
$user->save();

$accounts = new Account();
$accounts->email = $email;
$user->account()->save($accounts);

$userAccount = new UserAccount();
$userAccount->userAccount()->sync([
   $user->id,
   $accounts->id
```

Laravel Relationships:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models

Laravel Queries:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#inserts

Answer (score 0):

You have the data from the first table so you're almost there. Based on the current format you can loop through it and `insert()` into the new table.

Some pseudo-code:

```
foreach ($data as $inData) {
    DB::table('some_new_table')->insert(['column1' => $inData->column1, 'column2' => $inData->column2, ...]);
}
```

Comment: I did like this:

public function index()
    {
        $data = DB::table('incidencias')
       ->join('clientes_incid', 'clientes_incid.rif', '=', 'incidencias.rif')
       ->select('incidencias.rif')
       ->distinct()
       ->get();

        return view('ATC.index', compact('data'));

        
      foreach ($data as $inData) {
      DB::table('clientes_view')
      ->insert(['rif' => $inData->rif]);
      }

    }

but didn't fill the table in my database... how could I fix it... THanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view in your database for this situation.
create a migration and in up method write your sql, and it will fill automaticely by your database.

```
  public function up()
  {
    DB::statement("
      CREATE VIEW clients_view AS
      (
         // wirte your sql command here
      )
    ");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the data like this

```
DB::table('table')->insert($data);
```

Insert accept arrays

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required'
        ]);
        $category = new Category();
        $category->name = $request->name;
        $category->slug = str_slug($request->name);
        $category->save();
        Toastr::success('Category Successfully Saved','Success');
        return redirect()->route('admin.category.index');
    }
```