# Distant relationships between two models in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to build an application on `Laravel` where I'm having following models:

```
type
    id - integer
    name - string

companies
    id - integer
    name - string
    type_id - integer

contacts
    id - integer
    name - string

company_contact
    contact_id - integer
    company_id - integer
```

`Contact`  to `Company` are having `many to many` relationship with `company_contact` as table name and `Company` to `Type` are `belongsTo` relation.

I'm having a situation where I want to calculate count of companies as per type also same with contacts as per type. So in type model I did something like this:

```
class Type extends Model {

    public function companies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Company', 'type_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

and in controller I can simply do:

```
$types = Type::withCount('companies')
```

But in case of contacts I tried putting the `hasManyTrough` relationship:

```
public function contacts()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Contact', 'App\Company');
}
```

But is not working as desired, as per the documentation it `Contact` and `Company` should have `has Many` relation to execute this but I have `many to many` relationship.

Comment: Have you tried this one `https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many`

Comment: @DhavalPurohit I don't think many to many relationship will do in this type of situation.

Comment: Maybe you want `withPivot()` instead? Example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24995024/3585500 and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has no native support for a direct relationship.

I've created a package for cases like this: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

```php
class Type extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function contacts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(
            Contact::class,
            [Company::class, 'company_contact']
        );
    }
}

$types = Type::withCount('contacts');
```