# Laravel table inheritance. How to create relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following tables that represent a Purchase. A Purchase contains **many** items. An item can be of two possible types MaterialItem / ServiceItem.
A Material Item has a Material associated while a ServiceItem only contains a few text fields.

Table "purchases_item_base" contains the columns in common of the two possible item types.

How can I define two relationships in my Purchase model, one for retrieving the associated Material Items and another for the Service items?

```
    // TABLE 1 purchases
    Schema::create('purchases', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements("id")->unsigned();            
        $table->text("details");            
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });



    // TABLE 2 purchases_item_base
    Schema::create('purchases_item_base', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements("id")->unsigned();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger("purchase_id")->unsigned();          
        $table->decimal("price", 15 , 2);            
        $table->unsignedTinyInteger("priority");
        $table->text("obs");
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('purchases_item_base', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('purchase_id')->references('id')->on('purchases');            
    });



   // TABLE 3 materials
    Schema::create('materials', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements("id")->unsigned();
        $table->string('color');
        $table->string('weight');
        $table->string('brand');
        $table->string('model');
    });



    // TABLE 4 purchase_item_material
    Schema::create('purchase_item_material', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger("base_item_id")->unsigned();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger("material_id")->unsigned();
        $table->unsignedInteger("quantity")->default(1);
    });

    Schema::table('purchase_item_material', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('base_item_id')->references('id')->on('purchases_item_base');
        $table->foreign('material_id')->references('id')->on('materials');
    });




    // TABLE 5 purchase_item_service
    Schema::create('purchase_item_service', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger("base_item_id")->unsigned();
        $table->string("pn_number");
        $table->text("description");
    });

    Schema::table('purchase_item_service', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('base_item_id')->references('id')->on('purchases_item_base');            
    })
```

Comment: you need to use `hasManyThrough` relation for this situation.

Comment: I don't know how ? I supposed a polymorphic relationship was needed for this. As you can see I have a FK in the two item types table (purchase_item_material, purchase_item_service).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994640/laravel-hasmanythrough

Comment: @FarrukhAyyaz I don't see how I will get all the data contained in the table that's in the middle from this

Answer (score 0):

Try using one to many polymorphic relation

See documentation for better understanding https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations