# What am I doing wrong with Laravel hasManyThrough Multiple Foreign Keys?

Tags: laravel

I have previously had some confusion with the hasManyThrough and after re-reading the documentation a few times I normally manage to work it out. However, I'm struggling to do it this time and I think it's because I'm confusing myself with some different foreign key names.

I am using Laravel 10

I have 3 tables - orders, order_items, products

```
Orders:
id
name (this is the order name - there is a requirement to generate a name for the order, not the customer, using the most common product category)

Order_Items:
id (record ID)
order_id (order ID)
sku (foreign key to product)

Products:
id
name
category_id (foreign key to a category table not listed here)
sku (foreign key to order_items)
```

In the Order Model I am attempting to use a hasManyThrough relationship to get the products via the order_items table.

I am using the following code in the Order Model but there are no products being returned.

```
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Product::class, OrderItem::class, 'order_id', 'sku', 'id', 'sku');
    }
```

DDing the join shows the operators are matching the correct fields

```
          +wheres: array:1 [
            0 => array:5 [
              "type" => "Column"
              "first" => "order_items.sku"
              "operator" => "="
              "second" => "products.sku"
              "boolean" => "and"
            ]
          ]
```

```
      +wheres: array:1 [
        0 => array:5 [
          "type" => "Basic"
          "column" => "order_items.order_id"
          "operator" => "="
          "value" => 1
          "boolean" => "and"
        ]
      ]
```

But I am still getting no products - can anyone see where I have gone wrong? The $order->products is returning null attributes back

I have also tried

```
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Product::class, OrderItem::class, 'order_id', 'id', 'sku', 'sku');
    }
```

and

```
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Product::class, OrderItem::class, 'order_id', 'id');
    }
```

And some other variations of swapping round the variables but DDing the eloquent shows that the join wasn't working and was linking IDs to SKUs

I have done a lot of searching on Google and StackOverflow to no avail
The nearest related article I've found is [Laravel hasManyThrough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994640/laravel-hasmanythrough) but it is a bit outdated and is using ID to ID not an ID on one table and SKU on another

Also I do have multiple products that should be returning which I can see have matching SKUs and Order IDs if I manually browse the DB with PHPMyAdmin

Thanks in advance

Comment: hi, is this your query ```$order->products()->get();``` ??

Comment: I can't believe that. After an hour or so of moving the foreign keys around I forgot the basics. I missed the `->get();` - After adding this it works as expected. Thank you so much.